# spring boot not finding liquibase on IntelliJ startup

Tags: intellij-idea, spring-boot

I am running Spring 1.2.1.RELEASE with Liquibase in IntelliJ 14:

**build.grade**

```
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:$springBootVersion")
 compile('org.liquibase:liquibase-core')
```

I have a **project/config/application.properties** that I use to tell Liquibase to create the database and insert data:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydb
spring.datasource.username=xxx
spring.datasource.password=xxx
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.jpa.database=POSTGRESQL   
spring.jpa.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=none
spring.jpa.hibernate.disableConnectionTracking=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.default_schema=xxx

liquibase.change-log:classpath:/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml
liquibase.check-change-log-location=true
```

If I run from the command line:

```
gradle clean build
```

I will get all my tables and seed data in my database as expected.  But if I run my main SpringBoot Application class from within IntelliJ no tables are created.  I have a logging file that shows liquibase being used from the command line, but when I run from within IntelliJ, there is not mention of Liquibase in that log file.  Just to be sure, I have a duplicate application.properites under **project/src/resources**.

Here is how my project looks i IntelliJ:
[image]

Any ideas on how to get the properties file used from within IntelliJ?

Comment: Does it help if you do "Build" -> "Rebuild Project" immediately before running from within IDEA (without any "gradle clean" in between)? Apparently there is a problem where gradle and IDEA keep non-class files in separate folders so the two can interfere leading to files not being on the classpath when run from inside IDEA.

Comment: Unfortunately not.  Do I need to configure IntelliJ to know about the properties file?  I used the idea plugin to create the project structure and updated my question with the project module.

Comment: If you put application.properties in src/main/resources it should be picked up when running from within IntelliJ

Comment: `src/main/resources` is a must if that is not done.  Are you running any profiles?  Is IntelliJ setup with a profile?  I normally include this `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto: none`  Are you running in Debug mode?

Comment: I have the exact application.properties under both /config and /src/main/resources and its still not picked up.  This is the same for both debug and run.  If I am running profiles, I am unaware of what that is or how it would have gotten setup.